# Foundation is not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, zurb-foundation

I am working on an application using foundation framework but when I see the applicaion on IE version 8 and laters, the columns overlaps like in the image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qiyd.png)

I am using columns class from foundation, some like

```
<div class="large-10 columns" style="height:40px">
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <div class="large-5 columns">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="large-7 column">
            <a href="{{ url_for('loan', loan_id=loan['loan_id']) }}">
               <span class="subtable-item link">{{ loan['loan_id'] }}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

....

Somebody could help me with hacks for IE or some else that makes that tables look in the same way as Chrome.

Comment: Why don't post some code? I'm not able to help you in this way.

Comment: What happens in other browsers, are the contents clipped or are the columns more wide?

Comment: Foundation supports IE 9+

Answer (score 0):

you need open a new row for nested columns
try it

```
<div class="small-10 columns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-5 columns">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="small-7 column">
            <a href="{{ url_for('loan', loan_id=loan['loan_id']) }}">
                <span class="subtable-item link">{{ loan['loan_id'] }}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```